# Is this a right and most efficient way to remove blank string from NSArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsarray

Is this a right and most efficient way to remove blank string from NSArray?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *myStrings = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:(id[]){@"Test 1",@"",@"Test 2",@"Test 3",@""} count:5];
    NSArray *myFilteredArray = [myStrings filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length > 0"]]; //Non-destructive, myStrings is still intact

    NSLog(@"The original array is: %@",myStrings);
    NSLog(@"The filtered array is: %@",myFilteredArray);

    [myStrings removeObject:@""]; //Destructive. myStrings will never be the same again
    NSLog(@"The altered is: %@",myStrings);
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say removeObject is the most efficient way of removing the blank objects from your array. NSPredicate should be used for more complex structures, so in that respect it's an overkill given you could use removeObject.

Comment: Thanks Daniel..I think you got it perfectly right..!! Great Answer..!!